# key-value pairs in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I need to use an *associative array* as data source for my `select` options using AngularJS.

Is it possible to use an array like this?

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    ...
}
```

and get something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="key1">val1</option>
    <option value="key2">val2</option>
    <option value="key3">val3</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I read [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select), but I can't understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

#### use `ng-option`:

```
<select ng-model="blah" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in data"></select>
```

#### or use `ng-repeat`:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

#### data in controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    ...
};
```

Comment: I would highly recommend avoiding the ng-repeat method as it adds 2 new watches for each key/value pair. So basically if your select contains 50 items, you just created 100 new watchers. Yikes.

Comment: Is it possible to reserve the order? I get options in random order this way.

Comment: You should use array for order. JavaScript object iteration will be random order for some performance concern.

Comment: If you need to use `ng-repeat` and your keys/values don't change, I think you can avoid the 2 new watches @MarkusHay mentioned by using the new [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) syntax: `<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" value="{{::key}}">{{::value}}</option>`

Comment: Thanks, much clearer than the official doc for `ngOption`.

Comment: **use ng-option:** I saw many solution for `ng-options` based on `object` but this is the **best**.

Comment: very nice, but not able to set default selected item using 'ng-options'

Comment: ng-options only seems to work when the ng-model attribute is set on the select element, hopefully this saves someone else my headaches.

Comment: @Chen-TsuLin I need help Please view ones this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41223958/2143446)

Answer (score 21):

The following article discusses the variety of ways that you can use ngOptions (by far the clearest, most thorough explanation I've ever seen): http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks man, have to say that the link is the best till date. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Answer by [Chen-Tsu Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3012290/chen-tsu-lin) actually gives both ways of accessing objects. Just want to add few more lines -

Because the `ng-repeat` directive repeats a block of HTML code for each item in an array, it can be used to create options in a dropdown list, but the `ng-options` directive was made especially for filling a dropdown list with options and has at least one important advantage:

> Dropdowns made with `ng-options` allows the selected value to be an
>   object, while dropdowns made from `ng-repeat` has to be a string.

Adding an example for the reference:

`ng-repeat` : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_repeat_selected

`ng-options`: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_object

For complete reference, head onto http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp