# {{value}} is not getting resolved in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JSON**:

```
[
  {
    "1": "January",
    "2": "February",
    "8": "August",
    "9": "Septemeber",
    "10": "October",
    "11": "November",
    "12": "December"
  },
  {
    "2": "February",
    "3": "March",
    "4": "April",
    "5": "May",
    "6": "June",
    "7": "July",
    "8": "August"
  }
]
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class='W1_Normal V4 A_{{$parent.$index}}' style="width:100px;" id="A_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}"  name="A_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" onchange="modifiyOtherDropDowns(this);removeErrorMessagesOfAllLowerDivsUsingObj(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in ap" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

In Firefox and Chrome, above written code is working fine, `{{value}}` is getting resolved corresponding value. But in IE `{{value}}` is getting showed as `{{value}}`!

UPDATE:Problem specific to IE8

[image]

Comment: Don't use ngRepeat to build selects, use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: You can use ng-class to bind a model to a css class.
Does IE show a javascript error in F12 ?

Comment: Have you checked all the steps in here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: @Yoshi I know,I made a mistake by using ng-repeat. But does this have any concern with the issue I am facing?

Comment: @jao yes ,It is showing some error  "Object doesn't support this property or method" ,I am digging deeper in the issue ,thanks for pointing out.

Comment: IE compatibility mode might be the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags

Comment: @RishiPrakash To be honest, I wouldn't even bother checking. Just use ngOptions.

Comment: @Yoshi how can I have key,value as value,text in ng-options??

Comment: @Yoshi http://stackoverflow.com/a/21734643/3956550 this is the reason I used ng-repeat. :)

Comment: @Yoshi Well,what u suggested worked. But If I have to use ng-repeat ,will there be any suggestion to support this problem in IE8 too?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [article about using Angular with IE8 and earlier](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie). There are some tricks you need to know about. Whenever I target IE8 with Angular, I avoid writing element directives and stick with attribute directives instead.

Comment: I agree with you ,but this doesn't provide an answer to my Qus.

Comment: i think in this link point number 4 is the answer of your question

Comment: Yes Ahmer,it does. But see using ng-repeat  is also the right way to do. It's IE8 Engine which have some bug in it ,that why it doesn't render {{variable}} properly.

Comment: instead of ng-repeat try `ng-options`
[click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to view more detail