# How to set Pre selected data in dynamic select option in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, cordova, html-select, ionic-v1, angularjs-select

I face a strange problem where I need to show Pre selected data(which also come from server) in select option. The problem that I need to show select option based on key and value option.

```
       <div class="list list-inset">
            <span class="input-label">Permisstion</span>
            <select ng-model="permisstion" >
             <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in Roles" id="{{key}}" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

JSON Data

```
"Roles": {
        "21": "Admin",
        "22": "Main Manager",
        "23": "Branch Manager",
        "26": "Side Manager"
    }
```

I don't no how to show Pre selected data in select option and I try a lot but till now I don't get success.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Firt, your JSON is not a array of objects. I dont know if work in a `<select>` by objects atributes... by my other answer you can do something like in below.

Try to use like that:

```
"Roles" : {
           [
              {code: 21, name: "Admin"},
              {code: 22, name: "Main Manager"}, 
              {code: 23, name: "Branch Manager"},
              {code: 24, name: "Side Manager"}
           ]
          }
```

So the atribute "code" will be my index to the select:

```
<select ng-options="role.name for role in Roles track by role.code">
        <option value="">They see me rollin</option>
</select>
```

What I do was use track by role.code, as you can watch in this [video](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/).

REMEMBER: If code reapet in the array of objects it will break the `<select>`.